# How can i create a border outside a div like showed in image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I am trying to create the border around the section as shown in the image but not sure how can move it few pixels out of the main box.
Here is what I tried but its not exactly what I want.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="section-steps row outside" id="cities">

<div class="row">
    <h2>Our Values</h2>
</div>
<div class="row js--wp-1 our-values-image-container">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3 box">
        <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Animal Welfare</h3>
        <div class="img-background">
            <img src="resources/img/animal_welfare.jpg" alt="Animal Welfare">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3 box">
    <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Food Safety</h3>
        <div class="img-background">
            <img src="resources/img/food_safety.jpg" alt="Food Safety">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3 box">
        <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Sustainability</h3>
        <div class="img-background">
            <img src="resources/img/Sustainability-S.JPG" alt="Sustainability">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img-background{
    background: #ffd203
}
.our-values-image-container{
    padding: 0px 40px;
}
```

Here is the output:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add box shadow to the image

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: -30px -30px 0px yellow;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use some CSS properties:

1. The [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property that may help you if the text goes out the `<div>` or the container.
2. I see that you may want to create a shape as background for your image, so the [shape](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/) property will help you.

After importing the image, the overflow property turns important here if you want to write on the image.

3. Now, with `position: absolute;` make your image stand above the shape. This will help you: [Position](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

I advise you to use classes and ID when using CSS.